Об авторском обособлении вводного слова "конечно"
Нужны запятые?
В кино(,) конечно(,) тоже, но там у тебя всегда есть право на ошибку и ты не подключаешься в полной мере надолго.
Меня заинтересовала дискуссия на другом ресурсе:
Слово "конечно"... мне кажется, оно вводное. Я бы 
обособил его запятыми с обеих сторон.

Постоянно выделять слово "конечно" запятыми — это 
тенденция последних лет, часто ошибочная. Выделите 
его — и акцент будет на "конечно", а без запятых 
акцент на "кино". Уберите "конечно" — и ничего не 
изменится. При чтении оно не выделяется голосом. По 
смыслу, красоте — запятые у "конечно" не нужны. Но 
большинство преподов сочтут их отсутствие за 
ошибку.  

Спасибо. Я понял Вас, понял Вашу идею. Но вот 
уважаемая "грамота.ру" таки считает, что это 
вводное слово. Я ей доверяю. Она меня много раз 
выручала. Большинство уверены в том, что "конечно" 
— это вводное слово. Хотя да, если взять 
предложение «Конечно ты прав!», то можно 
расценивать как усилительное. Так что в данном 
контексте, пожалуй, запятая не нужна...  

Правила меняются, и не в лучшую сторону. Раньше 
смотрели по смыслу, сейчас стремятся к 
однозначности и техничности. Когда я учился, у нас 
еще было правило "авторского знака": ученик мог 
доказать правильность своей пунктуации оттенком 
смысла. Вплоть до того, что на выпускном экзамене в 
спорных моментах могли попросить ученика объяснить, 
почему он поставил (или нет) запятую. Сейчас такого 
нет.  

Можно ли ОДНОЗНАЧНО решить эту задачу, то есть без упоминания авторских знаков? А также без сожалений о прошедших временах. И без "увы, такова нередко русская пунктуация". Да и разве что-нибудь изменилось в этом правиле?

 Слово "конечно"... мне кажется, оно вводное. Я бы 
 обособил его запятыми с обеих сторон.


Правильно кажется! Носители языка слышат правильное произношение вводных слов и интуитивно отличают их от наречий и частиц.

И правила не менялись Справочник по пунктуации
При употреблении в ответной реплике, произносимой тоном 
уверенности, убежденности, слово «конечно» может не 
обособляться: «Это правда?» – «Конечно правда!»


Но как убедителен оппонент, а возразить вроде бы не получается...
По смыслу, красоте — запятые у "конечно" не нужны. Но 
большинство преподов сочтут их отсутствие за 
ошибку.

Хотя да, если взять предложение «Конечно ты прав!», то 
можно расценивать как усилительное. Так что в данном 
контексте, пожалуй, запятая не нужна... 



Так чего стоят ваши знания, если нет уверенности, если красивые фразы меняют вашу точку зрения?

В большинстве случаев задача задача имеет однозначное решение, которое следует из СТРУКТУРЫ заданного предложения.  Эту структуру выбирает автор в соответствии с нужным ему значением слова.

В кино, конечно, тОже, но там у тебя всегда есть право на ошИбку.
Ударение в сложном предложении падает на тоже, а обособленное вводное слово уходит на второй план речи. Но этого не видит второй пользователь.

А если взять простое предложение: В кино, конечно, тоже.

Ничего не меняется? Ах да,  ведь нужна ответная реплика.
— А как в кино?
— В кино конечно тОже! Но там у тебя всегда есть право на ошИбку.
Или лучше так: И в кинО конечно. В кино конечно же тОже!
Ответы Грамоты о конечно же:
Примечание. Если есть возражение по решению, то можно обсудить. Каждый вариант индивидуален, да и правила могут пониматься по-разному.

В всех приведенных примерах слово "конечно" может не выделяется только в начале предложения. Остальная дискуссия по поводу не выделения в середине предложения не имеет никакого смысла!

А в каком справочнике написано, что только в начале. Если это ваш собственный вывод, то обоснуйте.  Я считаю, что "конечно"  не обособляется, если входит в состав предложения.  Вот у меня был пример: — Вход бесплАтный?  — Вход конЕчно бесплатный, но при желании вы можете передать фонду какие-нибудь средства.

№ 270148
Здравствуйте! Нужна ли запятая в предложении «Теперь-то(,) конечно!»? Спасибо.
ОТВЕТ
Запятая не требуется: Теперь-то конечно!

Утвердительная частица (в ответной реплике). То же, что «да». Обособляется или оформляется как отдельное предложение.
«В Соловце будете останавливаться?» – cпросил горбоносый. «Конечно, – сказал я. – Я в Соловец и еду». А. и Б. Стругацкие, Понедельник начинается в субботу. «Конечно, да, – грустно отвечал он. – Но как я скучаю без него, если бы вы знали!» В. Каверин, Два капитана.
@ Не выделяется знаками препинания слово «конечно» в начале ответной реплики, произносимой тоном уверенности, убежденности: Конечно же это так! Конечно правда!
.

Словарь-справочник по пунктуации. — М.: Справочно-информационный интернет-портал ГРАМОТА.РУ. В. В. Свинцов, В. М. Пахомов, И. В. Филатова. 2010

Шарон, а какое значение имеет слово "конечно" в этом предложении? Вход конечно бесплатный.

Серж, я хорошо знаю этот справочник и все, что там написано.  Роль слова "конечно"определяется по контексту в диалоге, И если есть сомнения в информации, то используется частица "конечно", на которую ставится ударение:  Вход конЕчно бесплатный.  В другом контексте это может быть вводное слово.  Не стоит забывать, что вводное слово не включается в состав предложения ни грамматически, ни интонационно, в отличие от частицы. И именно это является критерием при определении ф-ии слова, а совсем не обязательная позиция в начале предложения
